# $PATH - No such file or directory MAC OSX - Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, path

A million different version of this have been asked already, but I'm still lost, sorry. Here is some of what I'm getting back...

In a terminal:

```
$PATH
-bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin: No such file or directory

echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

cd..
-bash: cd..: command not found
```

Comment: You can refer to comments:[No such file or directory after typing $PATH in terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/881463/no-such-file-or-directory-after-typing-path-in-terminal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really asked a specific question but here are some comments that hopefully help you understand what's going on:

### ad 1

If you just enter

```
$PATH
```

into your terminal the shell `expands` the variable called `$PATH` and then `attempts` to execute its `contents` which, obviously, doesn't make much sense with regards to `$PATH`. Try running

```
$ foo=ls
$ $foo
```

and you will understand what happens. Note though that in most cases you do not want to store a command in a variable, you will want to read [BashFAQ/050 aka I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to learn a little bit about the edge cases and why this is generally a bad idea unless you know exactly what you are doing.

### ad 2

Using `echo $var` you are printing the contents of the variable `$var` to the screen. Note that `word splitting` can occur and usually you will want to *quote* your variables to avoid this:

```
$ echo "$var"
```

### ad 3

This does not work because `cd` is a command (OK, a shell builtin usually) and `..` is its parameter and the two need to be separated by whitespace so the shell's parser can pick these up as separate tokens:

```
$ cd ..
```

Note that you can set up an alias to make `cd..` work:

```
$ alias cd..='cd ..'
```

but I would advise against that and learn how to properly use a Unix shell instead of making it mimic `DOS`.