# No such file or directory after typing $PATH in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, path

when I write in terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

my output is

```
:/home/bo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

but when I write just :

```
$PATH
```

this output I do not understand right, output is:

```
bash: :/home/bo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory
```

and my question is, why did it write "No such file or directory?" every directory from PATH variable exists.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`$PATH` is a variable, which I am sure you're aware of. When that variable is resolved, it would be the same as typing in `:/home/bo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:` and expecting something to happen. The reason `echo $PATH` works is because you're explicitly piping it out to the display rather than telling the terminal to "do" `$PATH`.

Answer (score 5):

In case you still don't get it from the other answers, it's the same as this:

```
$ echo the quick brown fox
the quick brown fox
$ the quick brown fox
bash: the: command not found

$ echo and/or the black and white cats
and/or the black and white cats
$ and/or the black and white cats
bash: and/or: No such file or directory
```

The first word of every command line has to be a *command*. 
`echo` is such a command. 
`the`, `and/or`, and `:/home/bo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin…` are not. 
And, apparently, when you type a command line that begins with a word that isn't a command,
bash says `No such file or directory` if the word contains one or more `/` characters,
and `command not found` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

By typing

> $PATH

you are actually doing nothing else than expanding its content at command line:

> :/home/bo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

and this is not a valid command, legitimately leading to the message you are getting.

What did you expect that typing only `$PATH` will do?

Comment: I guess the expectation that `$PATH` would essentially print the variable to the screen without trying to execute it, however, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux the terminal is waiting for a `command`, $PATH is not a command , is a `variable`.

When you write `echo $PATH` you're asking the contents of the variable and with the command `echo` showing it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$PATH` contains multiple directories separated by colons. The shell is expecting an executable file or other command (e.g., a shell built-in command, like `cd`) as input. Commands such as `ls` and `cat` are just executables located in one of the $PATH directories. Multiple directories chained together by colons generally do not form a proper UNIX file path. Notice: if you enter just one of the directories without the colon, then you get a different output.